# ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack (Python)

Tags: python

When I run this code below I get a value error `need more than 1 value to unpack` on the line `for dt, value in group`. this is a few lines from my .csv file:

```
TimeStamp,Irradiance,Ambient_Temperature
21/7/2014 0:00,0.66,29.16
21/7/2014 0:00,0.71,29.16
21/7/2014 0:00,0.65,29.17
21/7/2014 0:00,0.67,29.17
21/7/2014 0:01,0.58,29.17
.
.
.
22/7/2014 23:58,0.69,28.54
22/7/2014 23:58,0.61,28.54
22/7/2014 23:58,0.65,28.51
22/7/2014 23:58,0.59,28.54
22/7/2014 23:59,0.63,28.55
22/7/2014 23:59,0.67,28.54
22/7/2014 23:59,0.68,28.56
22/7/2014 23:59,0.58,28.55
```

Code:

--------EDITED ------

Comment: So have you checked what `group` actually is? Also, please review your code indentation.

Comment: group refer to the datetime of csv file

Comment: So how do you think it can be unpacked to the two names `dt` and `value`?

Comment: how can i solve this error? btw, thanks for replying

Comment: i wanted to use try-except to print the length of group but i dont know how

Comment: In that case: https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: Fix the indentation in your code please.

Comment: do you have any idea of how to solve it?

Comment: will you please provide traceback?

Comment: Your csv looks comma-separated, but you use delimiter=b'\t'.  Change it to delimiter=','

Comment: hi lafada, 
traceback (most recent call last):
file "/home/plot8.py', line 18, in <module>
   for dt, value in group]
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of errors in your code. The first one is about your use of variable 'group' and the second one about your use of strptime. Try with this

```
from datetime import datetime, time
with open(r'data.cvs', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=b'\t')
    groups = itertools.groupby(reader, lambda row: row[0].split()[0])
    for date, group in groups:
        new_group = [(datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y"), value) for value in group]
        during_8to5 = [(dt, value) for dt, value in new_group if time(8) <= dt.time() < time(17)]
```

Comment: hi avanzo, thank you very much for replying, is your date time suppose to be separate?

Comment: hi avanzo, i corrected my code with your suggestion but i got two error:new_group = [(datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y"), value) for value in group] 2nd error is:     groups = itertools.groupby(reader, lambda row: row[0].split()[0]) which is a IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: try to revert delimiter to original version : delimiter=b'\t' as in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The indent in your code is error, I cannot figure out what you exactly want to do.
But I know the reason of your `ValueError`.

In the first code snippet, `reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=b'\t')`, you use `\t` as the delimiter. But the real delimiter in your csv file is `,`. So the value of `group` in the line `for dt, value in group` is a list which contains only one element, `['21/7/2014 0:00,0.66,29.16']`. So it is wrong to unpact.

In the second code snippet, `reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=b',')`. The value of `group` in the line `for dt, value in group` is a list which contains only three elements, `['21/7/2014 0:00', '0.66', '29.16']`. So it is still a error.

Maybe you can write the code like this:

```
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=b',')

for dt, value1, value2 in group
```